# FTP client with instant automatic update

Tags: ftp, automation

I've used a dozen FTP clients over the years, but only a few of them work with automatic updates when saving.

For example, The FireFTP addon for FireFox is great. You double click a file.. it opens in notepad++.. and when you click save, it immediately uploads the new version of the file to the server. Further changes can be made and each time you hit save, it uploads instantly.

I'm trying to find a standalone (preferably portable) FTP client that does this without prompting.

FlashFXP waits for you to hit ok and can desync if you hit cancel then reopen.

Filezilla prompts after save is detected but no way to just be automatic.

Coreftp prompts after file is closed

I've not found one yet that supports an automatic session or maybe I'm just not finding it

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post, but I found this functionality in WinSCP:

http://winscp.net

The feature is documented here:

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Ubuntu you can just mount the remote server as a drive in Nautilus ([got it here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94665/what-is-a-program-similar-to-winscp)) and edit any file in your preferred editor. Save and instant upload works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on OSX or Linux, give [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) a shot.

Comment: As I already listed filezilla above, that won't help. FileZilla is really overrated and terrible IMO. It amazes me how popular it is. FlashFXP has the simpler and still powerful interface... but is missing this one feature that even FileZilla doesn't have

Comment: oops...helps to read the entire question.  i thought there was a way to turn the nag off in FileZilla, but i guess i remembered incorrectly.  good luck...

Comment: Looks like there is a work around here for filezilla: http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=14672&start=15

Answer (score 0):

You need something like [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/windows) or [WebDrive](http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/index.html) or [DirectNet Drive](http://www.directnet-drive.net/index.php) to create a virtual disk that maps to remote FTP folder. Than any request (read, write etc) will go not to local copy but directly to the server.